# Google Webmaster Tools incorrect rel-alternate-hreflang implementation warning message

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, language, hreflang

I'm getting this warning message in Google Webmaster Tools:

> Incorrect rel-alternate-hreflang implementation  In particular, there
>   seems to be a problem with missing or incorrect bi-directional linking
>   (when page A links with hreflang to page B, there must be a link back
>   from B to A as well).

This message seems pretty straight forward, but when checking their example pages, I'm not finding anything wrong. I'm using alternate for translation of main site menu, titles, etc. In each page I have this:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mydomain.com/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="jp" href="http://ja.mydomain.com/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="http://ko.mydomain.com/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://th.mydomain.com/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.mydomain.com/page" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="http://pt.mydomain.com/page" />
```

I've double checked this exists in all the 6 pages. This is the first time I've seen this message although I've implemented this at least 6 months ago, and implementation hasn't changed. Is there any way to check a specific set of pages for these things? Am I missing something in my implementation?

We're auto-redirecting people from a location to their specific language, and give them an option to manually change this. I've also just found out about the suggestion for `Vary HTTP header` - is that relevant and important here?

Comment: I also received a similar message from Google Webmaster tool on Friday and after a thorough check I realised that maybe another tag - <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://mydomain.com/" />
Should be included, this should tell Google that a cross referencing tag is in place. Any thoughts?

Comment: Mark may have hit the nail on the head here if you are using a single page to redirect visitors to the other pages.

Comment: @moobot what to you mean by 'using a single page to redirect'? I have a main page (without subdomain per lang) that is in english, and redirect to other lang according to header accept lang. Should I just add `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="/http://mydomain.com/page>` to all pages?

Comment: Noam, if you would like to post your URL that might help.

Comment: Hmm, like your original post, seems ok to me. Might be best asking the question in the Google Forums.  Ignore my other comment, I don't think it's valid in this case. If you had a language/country selector page or auto-redirecting home pages, you should use  "x-default", but I doesn't look like you do.

Comment: @moobot Not sure I totally understand when to use x-default. I do have auto-redirects, they just add the relevant sub-domain, according to the header language information.

Comment: perhaps you should be using it then, more info here: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html

Comment: So maybe I should just change my hreflang="en" to x-default? Or would you advise to keep both with the same link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Webmaster gave me the same warning message again, this time with an *example*:

```
Value JP found on
```

So my problem was that I used `hreflang=jp` (like seen in my question) instead of using `hreflang=ja`. I verified this is actaully a language code mistake here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: I missed that, I'm glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Google appears to have a bug.  Other people have been asking about this in the Google product forums.  [Google's Christopher Semturs says](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/Elb7F6XVq0w/uBEjgNmN6IUJ):

> …we are looking into this. As long as you do not get a mail with better examples you should not worry, the general setup looks sane.