# Incorrect rel-alternate-hreflang implementation

Tags: sitemap, mobile, internationalization, hreflang

Google Webmaster Tools advised the following to us:

> We have noticed that on a number of the pages on your site the
>   rel-alternate-hreflang implementation is incorrect. In particular,
>   there seems to be a problem with missing or incorrect bi-directional
>   linking (when page A links with hreflang to page B, there must be a
>   link back from B to A as well). When our algorithms detect conflicting
>   signals like on these pages, they may make indexing and ranking
>   decisions that do not match what you intended.

The links they mention in particular are:

http://www.kogan.com/au/careers/

You can see the sitemap for that particular URL at http://www.kogan.com/au/sitemap-pages.xml

In particular:

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.kogan.com/au/careers/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/careers/"/>
</url>
```

Or the URL http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/, the sitemap for which can be found at http://www.kogan.com/au/sitemap-collections.xml

In particular:

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="http://www.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" href="http://www.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://www.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://m.kogan.com/#!/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="canonical" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="https://m.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://m.kogan.com/#!/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
<mobile:mobile/>
</url>
```

I'm not quite sure, based on reading of the spec, where I'm going wrong. Is it cause the mobile URL is not linking back to the desktop URLs? Or it cause the URL is being linked to the same URL for `hreflang="en-AU"`?

I'm aware of a similar question at [Google Webmaster Tools incorrect rel-alternate-hreflang implementation warning message](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/google-webmaster-tools-incorrect-rel-alternate-hreflang-implementation-warning-m) which hints at this being a bug on Google's side, though I'd love to get some confirmation or know if there is some blatant error with my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very few sites get this right, the complex permutations are very confusing.

It appears that you may have two different issues here:

**1st Example (Careers):**
You are indicating, using the `rel=alternate` reference, that there are other versions of that URL, when there is only one. You only need to self-reference when there are other alternates. This circular referencing could be causing the "bi-directional" (A->B, B->A) error.

A correction of the example code you gave would be:

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.kogan.com/au/careers/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

**2nd Example (Collections):**
Mistake #1: You're providing two alternate URLs to the mobile version for each URL (hashbang and non-hashbang versions), and then providing alternate language versions of those mobile URLs.

Mistake #2: You're referencing mobile URLs in the `<loc>` elements your desktop XML sitemap - this is not needed as the `rel=alternate media=` takes care of this. You only need to provide mobile URLs in a [mobile XML sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34648).

Mistake #3: You were using `<mobile:mobile>` mark-up in your desktop XML sitemap, this should only be restricted to *feature phone* or *smartphone* XML sitemaps . It would be worth re-reading in detail the specifications (in the above link) again.

Mistake #4: The biggest issue is that you're **not** referencing the other versions in the `<loc></loc>` as their own entities - [as per the spec](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587), and as per the warning about 'bi-directional' annotation.

You should consider restricting the mobile alternate URL markup to the `<head></head>` of your documents. Remember that `rel=canonical` to the desktop URL [is required](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details#separateurls) to be included in the head of your mobile pages

A correction of your second example code would look like:

```
<url>
     <loc>http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/</loc>
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="http://www.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" href="http://www.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://www.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="http://www.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" href="http://www.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://www.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
    </url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="http://www.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" href="http://www.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://www.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
    </url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="http://www.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="http://www.kogan.com/ii/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-NZ" href="http://www.kogan.com/nz/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://www.kogan.com/uk/shop/collection/mac-mini/"/>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.9</priority>
    </url>
```

You also need to be very careful in using `rel=canonical` in this situation (see answer to this post: https://plus.google.com/+RichardHearne/posts/SpSnNfv3f1a)

Comment: Another thing I see is that your https://m.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/ URLs have a meta-fragement specified on them, but don't respond with a rendered page under https://m.kogan.com/au/shop/collection/mac-mini/?_escaped_fragment_= ... I'd also add a rel=canonical from the mobile pages to the desktop ones. That said, there are a lot of things to work on here, so I'd recommend finding someone with whom you can double-check the implementation (who has done these things before), to move forward a bit faster.

Comment: Good pick-up @JohnMueller - I was hoping you would chime in on this  :)

Comment: @MikeHudson Thanks! Really appreciate your help with this! I've fixed the `/au/careers/` location to remove the self-referencing. With the collections map, I'll try and address your comments. **Mistake#1**: Fixed to include just non-hashbanged URLs (is there a preference which ones to use?) **Mistake#2** + **Mistake#3**: Reason we're including Mobile URLs in the desktop sitemap is because https://m.kogan.com/robots.txt points the crawlers to this sitemap. Is this okay? Or should we completely separate the files?

Comment: @MikeHudson **Mistake#4** Not sure this is a mistake. There are bi-directional references, just in separate files. Eg: http://www.kogan.com/au/sitemap-collections.xml and http://www.kogan.com/nz/sitemap-collections.xml - Do they need to be in the same file? Also, with the mobile URLs, do they need their own `rel="alternate" hreflang`, so should pointing to the desktop using `rel="canonical"` and the desktop pointing to different `hreflang` URLs be fine?

Comment: @JohnMueller Ah, noted! We removed the `meta-fragment` tag as it was not working. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravDadhania for your additional questions: #3 - you should have distinct/separate XML sitemaps for Desktop/Smart-Phone/Feature-Phone URLs (if they differ, and depending on your implementation). #4 - It would be smarter to group those bi-directional references, but I've never tested them separated to see if that's an impact. Mobile URLs shouldn't really need their own `hreflang` if you're correctly managing redirection for mobile user-agents (see similar question on Google here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/_UwZqAVpXEs